# Заменить знак * на цифру

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы

Надо в масиве `a = ['*','1','2','*','*','4','*','*']` заменить `*` на число `1` а потом вивести масив без `[]` и `''`

Comment: А что у вас не получается?

Comment: не знаю как заменить все знаки *  на число

Comment: Начните с того, что пройдите по элементам списка. Да, и почитайте сначала про списки в питоне, это не массив.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как вариант

1. объединить строки которые содержатся в массиве в одну строку через 'join()'

   ```
    text = ''.join(arr)
   ```
2. заменить в строке звездочки на символ 1 через `replace()`

   ```
    text = text.replace('*', '1')
   ```
3. вывести строку посимвольно через `print` и `*`

   ```
    print(*text)
   ```

Ну и можно несколько извратов

способ 1:

```
print(*[i if i != '*' else '1' for i in arr])
```

способ 2:

```
print(*map(lambda i: i if i != '*' else '1', arr))
```

способ 3:

```
print(*''.join(arr).replace('*', '1'))
```

способ 4:

```
print(' '.join(arr).replace('*', '1'))
```